# Show that $f$ attains a minimum at the origin.

Tags: analysis

> Suppose $y=\varphi(x)$ is differentiable at $x=0$, $\varphi(0)=0$, $f$ is two-times continuously differentiable at an open neighborhood of $(0,\,0)$, $\nabla f(x,\,\varphi(x))=0$, and the Hessian matrix of $f$ at $(0,\,0)$ is nonzero and positive semi-definite. Show that $f$ attains a minimum at the origin.

It suffices to prove $f_x'(0,\,0)=f_y'(0,\,0)=0$. I don't know what $\nabla f(x,\,\varphi(x))=0$ implies.

Comment: could it be that instead of $\Delta f$ the expression was $\nabla f$?

Comment: Corrected. Sorry, my fault.

Comment: First of all the notation 
$$\nabla f(x,y)=0$$
means that the **gradient vector** of the function $f$ is equal $0$.

The gradient vector is defined as 
$$\nabla f(x,y)=\bigg(\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}},\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{y}}\bigg)$$

I suppose that by $\nabla f(x,y)=0$ the problem intends to say that
$$\nabla f(x,y)\vert_{(0,0)}=0$$


The hessian matrix being positive semi-definite at the origin implies that the function is convex at the origin.